# Homophonous words to pronounce differently

Tags: homophones

We have a nice Scottish native speaker at the university who is constantly smiling and she is not pretending it. She is always up for some lovely chat but last time I met her I felt so down that I did not even smile back.

Next time we meet in the morning, I want to say something to let her know that I am not impolite but down.

*Here is my idea:*

> Instead of saying **Good morning**, I want to say (in a funny way) **Good mourning**.

How should I put it (given that these two are homophonous) so that she understands what I mean?

I know this is a silly question but spare my life, please.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bother with the "morning/mourning" pun.  It doesn't let her know that you are feeling down.

Morning and Mourning are pronounced slightly differently (check a dictionary). But even if I did notice the change I would just find it a very odd thing to say.  "Good mourning" would mean "I hope you enjoy being sad for someone who has died recently"  I'm sure that's not what you want to say, and it's not very funny.

It not impolite to look sad. But if you are worried, next time you meet just say "Sorry I looked so sad (last week).  I was feeling down because...." Then she can listen and perhaps help.

Comment: I'd say that 'morning' and 'mourning' are pronounced differently in many places, but not everywhere (for instance where I come from).